# Many to one relationship, unwanted JOIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have many to one relationship defined within my model:
Project.CreatedBy = ApplicationUser.Id:

```
class Project{
[Required]
public ApplicationUser CreatedBy {get; set;}
}
```

With mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(i => i.CreatedBy).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Unfortunatelly, when I try to retrieve all users from DbContext by:

```
var users = context.Users;
```

Generated SQL looks like:

```
SELECT 
[...]
FROM     [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Projects] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent4].[CreatedBy_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[CreatedBy_Id])
```

So when certain user have created 10 projects, the user entity is multiplied 10 times. It makes me impossible to look for that user by his username:

```
context.Users.Single(u => u.Username == "test")
```

because it would give me **Sequence contains more than one element** exception.

Do you have any idea how to avoid that extra join?

I suspect it has something to do with modelBuilder declaration. I've been googling about this, but never found any solution.

Any materials about modelBuilder and defining relationships with it would be really appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.CreatedBy)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
```

...expresses this as a 1:1 association, not the 1:n association you intend it to be.

So change the mapping into one-to-many:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedBy_Id);
```

I'm not sure why EF joins in the `Project` when you query `User` because the association is optional), but a proper 1:n mapping will stop this.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it's working. I'm assuming, that "WithMany" refers to many Projects created by User, right? Could you recommend any materials about modelBuilder?

Comment: Yes it does. If `ApplicationUser` has a property `Projects` it should be `WithMany(u => u.Projects)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.FirstOrDefault()
```

instead of Single.

This method will return first object or null if object is not found. Single method throws exception if more than one element is selected.

You can also use

```
.First()
```

But this method will throw exception if no elements found.

PS I'm not sure if it's a typo, but you have to use double equal sign, like that:

```
context.Users.Single(u => u.Username == "test")
```

And keep in mind that usually in these cases LoweredUsername column is created and used for compare:

```
context.Users.Single(u => u.LoweredUsername == providedUsername.ToLower())
```

Reasons for that:

- Someone can type John instead of john
- Indexing on SQL server side works in this case

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the main problem - unwanted join. I see no reason to join all related entities when I want to retrieve ApplicationUser entity, but thank you for pointing out LoweredUsername.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in ApplicationUser you have

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

Please see [turn off lazy loading for all entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazyOff) in MSDN

Or to [turning off lazy loading for specific navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazyOffProperty) make the Projects property non-virtual